# Unable to use mouse/keyboard through VNC Viewer

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, mouse, vnc, remote

I just installed VNC Server on my remote server and ensured that the viewer mode is off. Still, the keyboard and mouse inputs are somehow disabled in the VNCViewer.

[image]

Access from: Windows 10

Remote Server: Ubuntu 20.04

What to do?